# how can I optimize this code? (php + querys)

Tags: php, sql

I have this marriage system in my game where 2 characters can marry each other, I want to show on my website who's married to who on their profile, this is the marriage table.

```
CREATE TABLE marriage_system (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    player_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    partner VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    marriage_date INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and this is my pdp code

```
<?php
    $is_married = false;
    $player_id = (int)$user_id;
                $db_query = "
                    SELECT `partner` AND `player_id`
                    FROM `marriage_system` 
                    WHERE `player_id`={$player_id} 
                    OR `partner`={$player_id}
                ";
    $valuekeeper = mysql_select_multi($db_query);
    $marriedto2 = ($valuekeeper !== false) ? (int)$valuekeeper['partner'] : 0;
    $partnerof = ($valuekeeper !== false) ? (int)$valuekeeper['player_id'] : 0;
    if ($marriedto2 != false){
        $is_married = true;
        $db_query = "
                    SELECT `name`
                    FROM `players` 
                    WHERE `id`={$marriedto2} 
                ";
        $db_query2 = "
                    SELECT `name`
                    FROM `players` 
                    WHERE `id`={$partnerof} 
                ";
        $nameofmarried = mysql_select_single($db_query);
        $nameofmarried = (string)$nameofmarried['name'];
        $nameofpartner = mysql_select_single($db_query2);
        $nameofpartner = (string)$nameofpartner['name'];
    }   
?>
                <!-- is married? $nameofpartner (name of partner) $nameofmarried (name of the other partner) $profile_data['name'] (name of the character which the profile page I'm visualizing rn) -->
                <?php if ($is_married): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Married to</b></td>
                    <td><a href="characterprofile.php?name=<?php echo $nameofmarried == $profile_data['name'] ? $nameofpartner : $nameofpartner; ?>"><?php echo $nameofparter; ?></a></td>              
                </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

I believe it's possible to make it work with only 1 select and with one if instead of these separete 2 but I barely know anything of php as this is basically one of my first codes but I want to make it right

---

edit: I changed the code above based on the comments bellow and it looks better but I'm seing this error when trying to visualize the profile of a player that is married to another one

```
Notice: Undefined index: partner in E:\xampp\htdocs\characterprofile.php on line 69
Notice: Undefined index: player_id in E:\xampp\htdocs\characterprofile.php on line 70
```

Line 69 and 70 are

```
$marriedto2 = ($valuekeeper !== false) ? (int)$valuekeeper['partner'] : 0;
$partnerof = ($valuekeeper !== false) ? (int)$valuekeeper['player_id'] : 0;
```

Comment: Your table design would be easier to use if `partner` was actually another foreign key to the `players` table (i.e. it was their `id`, not their `name`).

Comment: Actually partner is also a foreign key from players, but reading what you said enlightned me and I'll try to make some changes and edit the post if I arrive to something better that works

Comment: Ah, ok, it wasn't clear from the question. It does make more sense to use the `id` value, as it is possible(?) that two players could have the same name.

Comment: names are always unique tho they can be changed unique. I can't think of a way to improve my cude using the id of marriage_system tho

Comment: Actually looking at your code it looks like you're trying to use `partner` as a foreign key to `player_id` as you have `WHERE \`partner\`={$player_id}` in one query?

Comment: yeah I think that's it because the thing is: partner and player_id are regular `id` values from the table `players`, if I know who is either the parter or the player_id of the specific id of `marriage_system` I can find the other. I'll edit my post with some stuff that I changed and also point to an error I cannot get past of

Comment: OK, ping me when you've done that, I think your code can be simplified significantly.

Comment: @Nick updated ;)

Comment: Immediate issue: `SELECT \`partner\` AND \`player_id\`` should be `SELECT \`partner\`, \`player_id\``.

Comment: I couldn't format here, the errors I got with your code on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/Xt8hBi9S